# How to redirect multiple domain names to one unique domain name with input parameters

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I would like to know what would be the best strategy to point many domain names to one unique domain name with an input GET param. For example:

- www.domain1.com pointing to www.uniquedomain.com?referal=1
- www.domain2.com poitning to www.uniquedomain.com?referal=2
- www.domain3.com pointing to www.uniquedomain.com?referal=3
- www.domain4.com poitning to www.uniquedomain.com?referal=4

I would like to achieve this under an Apache hosting.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with DNS. You'll need to point your DNS records to a host running an HTTP server and then use rewrite rules to make the URL according to your needs based on the HTTP referrer.

Comment: Could you explain me how to do this @Wesley? Thanks.

Comment: @JeanPaulRuiz You'll want to use the `HTTP_REFERER` variable in Apache. The specifics will be left as an exercise for you. =)